# How to avoid getting a 'buffered' collision callback after re-starting Physics in Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, box2d, coronasdk

Background:
* using Corona SDK and the physic's functions here
* have tracked down an annoying problem I've had
* in this game I pause physics, then later I reposition my player object & restart (start) physics again
* what I see is a collision event firing that I wasn't expecting, as the player isn't near an object after I reposition it
* so I'm guessing that it is the carry-over of some previous collision that occurred

QUESTION: How can I avoid getting a "buffered"/"superfluous" collision event happening here, directly after starting the physics engine???

Comment: Question asked another way:  Is there any way in Box2D to "clear" any outstanding collision events between objects, or an object and a sensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Box2D is notorious for having problems like this... The only thing I guess you can do is store somewhere that you moved the player, and ignore the first collision and reset the flag...

Or you should delete the player and create it again.

Box2D hates when you move objects (even while paused) on your own.

Comment: the only trouble is it doesn't happen every time - so I guess I could check to see what the collision was with and then decide from this info whether it was from a previous phase.  I was already removing the physics body and re-adding.   So no way in Box2D to "clear" any outstanding collision events between objects, or an object and a sensor?

Comment: Not that I know of, not even in C++, but the last time I used Box2D with C++ is two years already...